# I am an Getting Error when Cloning git clone

Tags: git

I am trying to clone and when I run this code:

```
!git clone https://github.com/pratikkayal/PlantDoc-Object-Detection-Dataset.git
```

on Jupyter notebook I get  the following error:

```
Cloning into 'PlantDoc-Object-Detection-Dataset'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
error: 4691 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

What should I do, I have googled many solutions but none of them work.

Comment: Do you have enough disk space? The repo looks to be about 1GB in size...

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: If you're using Windows, just checking the remaining disk space with Windows Explorer will tell you. On Win10, open My PC to display the computer's drives. Assuming you just have the C: drive, right-click on it and select Properties. You can then look at Free Space. However, the error indicates an issue with security settings somewhere - perhaps on your computer, more likely on a network firewall. Try installing [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) and cloning the repo through there. Alternatively, [...]

Comment: [...] on the repo's web page, click on the Code button, then select the Download ZIP option.

Comment: After cloning using github desktop, I dont need to run this code : !git clone https://github.com/pratikkayal/PlantDoc-Object-Detection-Dataset.git right?

Comment: Correct. The repo has already been cloned locally (in whatever folder you chose), so you'll just have to refer to that folder when running your other code through Jupyter.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further I am still new to this, sorry..

Comment: How do I refer to the folder? Thank you

Comment: In the tutorial or set of instructions that you're hopefully following, there will probably be some place where you enter the location where you saved the repo when you cloned it in Github Desktop. Your Python code needs that location so it can access the training and test label CSV files, as well as the datasets (the images and associated XML files) themselves. That's all I meant. BTW, while running through this tutorial, I strongly recommend find a friend or colleague with some more computer experience to help you. The comments here aren't really the best place to do that.